# Java Servlet: PrintWriter strange behaviour with variable

Tags: java, variables, servlets, printwriter

I'm learning how to program servlet by following these [1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/progservlet.htm#WBAPP255) [2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/servlet-142430.html) official tutorials.
I cannot find a solution to a simple question about the strange behaviour of PrintWriter class with variables.
The code is the following:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class ServletExample extends HttpServlet {

   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws IOException, ServletException
   {
    response.setContentType("text/html");       
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");  
    out.println("<title>First example</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<h2>System information</h2>");
    out.println("Host name: " + request.getRemoteHost() + "<br>");
    out.println("Remote address: " + request.getRemoteAddr() + "<br>");
    out.println("Port: " + request.getServerPort() + "<br>");
    out.println("Encoding: " + request.getCharacterEncoding() + "<br>");
    out.println("Method: " + request.getMethod() + "<br>");
    out.println("Protocol: " + request.getProtocol() + "<br>");
    out.println("Address: " + request.getRequestURI() + "<br>");
    out.println("Path: " + request.getPathInfo() + "<br>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    out.close();
    }
}
```

The output of the servlet on servlet container is displayed up to

```
out.println("<h2>System information</h2>");
```

I cannot figure out why, but I discovered that by splitting the following line into these lines works:

```
out.println("Host name: ");
out.println(request.getRemoteHost())
out.println("<br>");
```

I searched a lot on the Web, but I cannot find and answer.

I'm under ubuntu mate 16.04 LTS with apache tomcat 8 installed from repository.

Edit
I further investigate about such behaviour by trying different tomcat 7 under ubuntu mate 16.04 LTS and different OS windows 10 with xampp and tomcat 7. The result is the same.

So I took the Request Info official example present into examples folder installed together with tomcat.
The code of the example is this:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class RequestInfo extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("<title>Request Information Example</title>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    out.println("<h3>Request Information Example</h3>");
    out.println("Method: " + request.getMethod());
    out.println("Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI());
    out.println("Protocol: " + request.getProtocol());
    out.println("PathInfo: " + request.getPathInfo());
    out.println("Remote Address: " + request.getRemoteAddr());
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
}

/**
 * We are going to perform the same operations for POST requests
 * as for GET methods, so this method just sends the request to
 * the doGet method.
 */

public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
throws IOException, ServletException
{
    doGet(request, response);
}
}
```

As expected it does not work and its behaviour it is the same of the previous code. However, if I open prebuilt version inside the example folder it works.

Finally, by splitting each line into several lines it works as described before.
It is really strange behaviour.

Comment: What happens when you send valid HTML (i.e. with an opening body element, and not just a closing one)? What happens when you right-click and select "View page source"?

Comment: There are no web browsers that would care about the missing `<body>` tag but it's a good catch. I'd also like to know what you get if you log the output or print it to the console.

Comment: Do NOT close the output stream!

Comment: @DavidConrad thank you for the reply, of course the <body> tag is present in my code. I made a copy and paste mistake. However, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Jamie thank you for your reply. I also tried to remove close(), but it does not work.

Comment: @JBNizet the <body> tag is present in my code. By viewing the page source, I get `<html>
<head>
<title>First example</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>System information</h2>`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a StringBuilder object to generate the result, then.  You can, if desired, calculate the content length, which is useful in some situations.

```
StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
sbText.append("<html>")
    .append("<head>")
    .append(etc...);

String text = sbText.toString();
// Option A:
response.getWriter().print(text);

// Option B:
byte[] bytes = text.getBytes();
response.setContentLength(bytes.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(bytes);
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Both solutions do not work and give an exception. Moreover, Java String has getBytes() not toByteArray().

Comment: I changed getByteArray to getBytes.  What exception are you getting?

Comment: I get the following exception: `javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception: org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)` caused by: `java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory
 ServletExample.doGet(ServletExample.java:20)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)`

Comment: That seems very strange.  Maybe just try it with regular string concatenation instead of a stringbuilder, then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution at my strange problem. I tried also with latest tomcat v9.0.8 that uses jvm v1.8.0_171-b11 while I compiled my code with javac 1.9.
By using javac v1.8 it works.